# Unable to install apk as package name is invalid

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

I am stuck in a problem for days and now I am asking here
**Unable to install apk as package name is invalid,**

I have tried,

1. Clean/rebuild the project
2. invalidate the cache
3. Downgrade target/compile version (My current version is 33).
4. Changed release folder
5. Tried to debug and release apk

It is giving me this error on all devices. The devices which I have tried for first time though.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you share more information about your package name? What is the applicationId you have in build.gradle?

Comment: any update on this issue? have you managed to fix it ?

Comment: Where do you get this error? On the phone screen? In the IDE? In the `adb` commandline? Maybe add a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that  `android:exported="true"` launcher activity on manifest file

Comment: It is already true. I am to install it direct but not from an apk

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely a conflict with the currently installed version of the apk. Make sure both apk files are signed with the same valid signature. If you have a rooted device, there are ways to disable signature verification which would enable the conflicting apk to be installed. Otherwise, you will need to uninstall the existing apk before you can install the new version.

Comment: Apk is not installed on phone. I am installing it first time

Answer (score 0):

Does it actually compile and create an APK or does it fail doing so because the package name is actually invalid? If yes, check if you have invalid characters in the package name.
See the style guide for [package names](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#package_names).

If the compilation works but the install fails, check if you already have an app installed with the same package name. If in doubt, create a new emulator and install it there.

Comment: I have followed all rules, it is working perfectly fine when i directly run it but not installing when i build debug/release apk

Comment: That linked style guide is for Kotlin package names, not for Android APK packageNames! because there are plenty of apps that have upper case characters in their APK packageName and that doesn't seem to harm anybody.